# Count non-empty rows from a range (IF and OR)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, countif, sumproduct

I'm trying to count the number of non-empty rows from a certain range. So based on the example below:

- I want to count the number of rows from TABLE1 that have "X" in the "1st" or/and "2nd" column [B3:C20] (no matter in which column it has the value, even when in both, it counts as 1, but if in none then 0);
- do this separately for Type A [F3] or Type B [F4].

[image]

I created something like this, but it considers it as an AND function instead of OR, and doesn't look for the Type A/B from the first column:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[[#All],[1st]],"<>"&"",Table1[[#All],[2nd]],"<>"&"")-1
```

Tried also with SUMPRODUCT, but no luck. I know it could be easily solved by adding another column that would put an "X" if in one of the columns or both are not empty, but in this scenario, I have to work with what I presented. Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: What is your excel version? Do you have Excel-365?

Comment: A couple of points.  The various "xxxxxIF" and "xxxxxIFS" functions still *require* physical cell ranges or table columns, and cannot operate on arrays.  That means incorporating an "OR()" criteria into them using a logical array won't work.  :(  Second point, your concatenation of `"<>"&""` will just result in the condition being `<>`.  The null value is not concatenated because, well, it's null and the Excel function interpreter is meant to ignore null.

Comment: @Harun24hr Indeed, it's Excel 365.

Comment: @Max valuable tips, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Edit:*** For any version of excel ***No. of X***

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(--($B$3:$C$20="X"),{1;1})>0),--($A$3:$A$20=E3))
```

And for total-

```
=SUM(--($B$3:$C$20="X")*($A$3:$A$20=E3))
```

If you are on Microsoft-365 then could try to count ***No. of X***

```
=SUM(FILTER(--BYROW($B$3:$C$20,LAMBDA(a,OR(a="X"))),$A$3:$A$20=E3))
```

And for total count

```
=SUM(--(FILTER($B$3:$C$20,$A$3:$A$20=E3)="X"))
```

Here

- `BYROW($B$3:$C$20,LAMBDA(a,OR(a="X")))` will merge all B & C column into one as `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on `X`. Then `--` this supress these boolean values to numbers so that we can sum these. We can also use `MMULT()` instead of `BYROW()` function for older version of excel.
- Then `FILTER()` will keep only values related of ***Type A*** or ***Type B***. And then we will sum to get count.

[image]

Comment: I entered a comment that has disappeared in the last few minutes, was it deleted?  Also, your formula `=SUM(--($B$3:$C$20="X")*($A$3:$A$20=E3))` returns the total number of "X" values of each type, whereas the example was simply the total number of "Type A" and "Type B" entries.

Comment: @Harun24hr That's simply great. although I might have not explained the "All" column the best possible way. @Max was right, it was about the total number of each type, so this would do it as well: `=COUNTIF(A3:A20,E3)`. Nevertheless, your answers gives also the readers of this post an additional solution, which also is great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a tricky question, so let's figure it out.
Type A/Type B has four arrangements, ① X+""; ② ""+X; ③ X+X; ④ ""+"", now we need to find out the count of the first three arrangements, that is ①②③④ - ④.

So the formula is:

```
=countifs(A3:A20,"Type A")-countifs(A3:A20,"Type A",B3:B20,"",C3:C20,"")
```

The process is in the picture.
[image: process]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this works! I would slightly modify this function by making the "Type A" and "Type B" a reference to the cell, and also adding dollar signs to make the columns not slip: `=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$20,E3)-COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$20,E3,$B$3:$B$20,"",$C$3:$C$20,"")`

Comment: Yes, the "Type A" and "Type B" a reference to the cell, but I also thought it was a good practice and maybe try some much more difficult for "TypeC", and "Type D" ..... 

Answer (score 1):

Enter this formula in [F3] and copy to [F4]:

```
= SUM( (Table1[Type]=$E3) * ( ( (Table1[1st]="X") + (Table1[2nd]="X") ) > 0 ) )
```

Enter this formula in [G3] and copy to [G4]:

```
= SUM( (Table1[Type]=$E3) * ( (Table1[1st]="X") + (Table1[2nd]="X") ) )
```

[image]

Please note that as per the data provided the results are:

[image]

Comment: If you look at the posted example, the G3 and G4 values are the total number of Type A and Type B entries, not the total number ox X’s for each type.

Comment: @EEM The formula for [F3] and [F4] works perfectly! The "All" amount was just for the total number of the certain type not all of that type, but your solution provides an additional option.

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution which seems little lengthy but it works fine on all versions of Excel.

[image: Answer Pic:]

Comment: Could you also provide us with the formulas in text format? It makes it easier for us to test your answer and improves the search for it.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:A20="Type A"),(ISTEXT(B3:B20))+(ISTEXT(C3:C20))-((ISTEXT(B3:B20))*(ISTEXT(C3:C20))))

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:A20="Type A"),(--(B3:B20="X")+(C3:C20="X"))-(--(B3:B20="X")*(C3:C20="X")))
Please check the formula & Apologies for the long delay.. @claudius